# Time dependent covariate SPSS

Tags: spss, survival, predictor

I am attempting a time dependent covariate analysis using SPSS but end up running into some difficulties. This is the first time I am trying it using SPSS so would appreciate some advise or direction.

I have a study population where the outcome is death and time to death (defined as the time interval from visit 1 to death)

The variable I am studying is Infection and whether this decreases survival

An infection can happen at anytime from visit 1 till the end of the study. So I can't use kaplan Mier cause of bias.

I have been trying to use SPSS for time dependent covariate as follows

Using time to infection (Time from visit 1 to infection) T_*TimeInf I then try the model using death as an outcome, Time to death as the time variable and T_TimeInf as the covariate

My questions- I left the TimeInf field blank for all patients who did not have an infection. This is being read by SPSS as missing cases. Is this the correct way to run the analysis? Should I be running it a different way or am I missing a step?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

You should have a 0/1 variable for infection status. Then if infection occurs, you split the record at the time of infection and have two records per patient, with `InfectionStatus=0` from the entry to the study until the infection time `TimeInf`, and then `InfectionStatus=1` after that, to reflect the change in the exposure.